# CKAsset not Saved to CloudKit - All other fields are saved

Tags: ios, swift4, cloudkit

I have a CloudKit app that is basically a master detail setup with one
extra feature. Any detail object can be marked as the ActiveNote. When
the app is on an iPad, ONLY this ActiveNote is shown (no user
interaction). The app includes notifications and subscriptions with all
data in a custom zone in the private database. The app works well with
one exception.

There are only two record types. All data is stored with type CNote.
When a detail item is chosen to be shown on the iPad, I upload that data to a single record of
type ActiveNote. The ActiveNote data is used only by the iPad to
populate its read only version of the detail view. The iPad dynamically
changes whenever the phone user marks a record as active.

All fields are uploaded and correctly shown on the iPad with the
exception of the asset for an image. No asset is saved and I receive no
error messages. The save procedure for the normal CNotes uses the same
procedure but starts with an image from the camera which I reduce in
size. This is, of course a UIImage. I cannot get a save from this image.
If I change the code to load a static .png included in the app, the
upload does work correctly. It is only when trying to upload an image
from the DetailViewController. Since the image is originally an asset
anyway, I have attempted to reload a CKAsset image directly into the
ActiveNote and that does not work either.

Any guidance would be appreciated. Here is the code to save to the single ActiveNote. iOS 11, Xcode 9.3

```
func queryActiveNote() {

    recordZone = CKRecordZone(zoneName: "CNotes")

    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "ActiveNote", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE"))
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "noteName", ascending: true)
    query.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    privateDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: recordZone?.zoneID) { (results, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("error querying database\(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        } else {

            guard results?.count > 0 else {return}
            print("results?.count is \(String(describing: results?.count))")

            self.activeNote = results![0]

            self.activeNote!["noteName"] = self.detailItem?["noteName"]

            //save a bunch of other fields too

            let tmpDir = NSTemporaryDirectory()
            let tmpFile = tmpDir.appending("test.png")
            let tmpFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: tmpFile)

            //Main queue to avoid runtime warning that image needs to be on main thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard let tmpImage = self.imageView.image else {
                    print("guard let tmpImage failed")
                    return
                }

                guard let tmpImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tmpImage, 1.0) else {
                    print("guard let tmpImageData failed")
                    return
                }

                do {
                    try tmpImageData.write(to: tmpFileURL, options: .atomic)
                    print("the write of chosenImageData succeeded")
                } catch {
                    print("error writing chosenImageData to a file")
                }//do catch

                let asset : CKAsset = CKAsset(fileURL: tmpFileURL)
                self.activeNote!["noteImageData"] = asset

            }//main

            self.privateDatabase.save(self.activeNote!, completionHandler: { (record, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print("privateDatabase error saving activeNote: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
                } else {
                    print("modified activeNote record saved successfully")

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let ac = UIAlertController(title: nil , message: "Record was successfully saved as Active", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
                        ac.addAction(okAction)
                        self.present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }//main

                }//if error else
            })//save block

        }//if error else
    }//perform query block

}//queryActiveNote
```

Comment: A wild guess but maybe you place the code that saves the data within the chosenImageData succeeded do/catch block. Obviously you need to move the asset allocation too. I suspect this is a race-hazard, the code to save to icloud executes BEFORE the file is saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user3069232 should get credit for the answer. The code above does save
the record to CloudKit before the image file save has completed. I moved
the CloudKit save block inside the do catch block and the process is
successful. Since I'm guaranteed to have an image in all records (there
is a default) then making the CloudKit save conditional on having a
successful image save is ok.